# When does Le Cam's method give tight lower bounds for distribution testing?

Tags: st.statistics, computer-science, lower-bounds

In the context of statistical estimation or [distribution testing](https://theoryofcomputing.org/articles/gs009/gs009.pdf), *Le Cam's method* is a way to prove lower bounds on the minimax sample complexity ([[1](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/%7Ebinyu/summer08/yu.assoua.pdf),[2](https://github.com/ccanonne/probabilitydistributiontoolbox/blob/master/assouadlemma.pdf),[3](https://theinformaticists.com/2019/08/03/3603/),[4](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eaarti/Class/10704_Fall16/lec21.pdf)], further details below). My question is: for the special case of distribution *identity testing* (see below), under what conditions is the lower bound obtained via Le Cam's method tight? (i.e., equal to the minimax sample complexity up to constant factors.)

#### Distribution Identity Testing

Let $D$ be a distribution over a finite set $\Omega$ and fix $\varepsilon \in (0,1)$. A tester for $D$ is a (possibly randomized) algorithm $T$ that takes i.i.d. samples $X_1,\dots,X_n$ from an unknown distribution $Q$ over $\Omega$, and outputs either "$Q = D$" or "$Q \in \mathcal{B}$" where $\mathcal{B} = \{P: ~ \mathrm{d}_\mathsf{TV}(P, D) \geq \varepsilon\}$ and $\mathrm{d}_\mathsf{TV}$ denotes total variation distance.

The *minimax sample complexity* for $D$ is the minimal $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$\inf_{T} \sup_{Q \in \{D \} \cup \mathcal{B}} \mathbb{P}_{X \sim Q^n}\left[T(X_1,\dots,X_n) \text{ fails}\right] \leq 1/3.$$

#### Le Cam's Method

For the special case of distribution identity testing, Le Cam's method boils down to the following inequality:

$$\inf_{T} \sup_{Q \in \{D \} \cup \mathcal{B}} \mathbb{P}\left[T(X_1,\dots,X_n)  \text{ fails}\right] \geq \frac{1}{2}\left(1-\inf _{Q \in \operatorname{conv_n}\left(\mathcal{B}\right)} \mathrm{d}_{\mathrm{TV}}\left(D^n, Q\right)\right),$$
where $\operatorname{conv_n}\left(\mathcal{B}\right)$ is the convex hull of $\{Q^n: ~ Q \in \mathcal{B}\}$.

### What I Know So Far

- At least in some cases, Le Cam's bound is tight. For example, [[2](https://github.com/ccanonne/probabilitydistributiontoolbox/blob/master/assouadlemma.pdf)] mentions that it gives a tight lower bound for uniformity testing (the case where $D$ is the uniform distribution on $\Omega$).
- From von Neumann's minimax theorem, $$\inf_{T} \sup_{Q \in \{D \} \cup \mathcal{B}} \mathbb{P}\left[T(X_1,\dots,X_n)  \text{ fails}\right] = \\ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ \sup_{Q \in \operatorname{conv_n}\left(\{D \} \cup \mathcal{B}\right)} \inf_{T} \: \mathbb{P}_{X \sim Q}\left[T(X_1,\dots,X_n)  \text{ fails}\right].$$ It looks to me as if the right hand side here is somewhat related to Le Cam's lower bound, but it's not obvious to me when they would be equal.
- These papers [[5](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1902.05616.pdf),[6](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/David-Donoho/publication/38359512_Geometrizing_Rates_of_Convergence_II/links/5479194b0cf293e2da2b2f1c/Geometrizing-Rates-of-Convergence-II.pdf)] give some conditions for the bound to be tight, but they are fairly general and I'm not sure I fully understand them.